# Jmeter. Get current HTTP sampler body data from beanshell preprocessor

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Before send the query in HTTP Sampler I need to make some changes of this query in beanshell preprocessor. So, the question is how to access to current sampler body data from beanshell preprocessor? I can get Name,Path,IP, etc ( for example sampler.getPropertyAsString("HTTPSampler.domain")) but have no idea how to get the body data.

Comment: can you explain, what exactly in body data are you trying to use?

Comment: i want get the text of request which entered in textbox in Body Data tab.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kindly find answers below (assuming that we're talking about [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request))

- Name: `sampler.getName()`
- IP:   `sampler.getUrl().getHost()`
- Path: `sampler.getUrl().getPath()`
- If you need request parameters:

  ```
  Arguments arguments = sampler.getArguments();
  for (int i=0;i<arguments.getArgumentCount();i++)
  {
      Argument argument = arguments.getArgument(i);
      String name = argument.getName();
      String value = argument.getValue();
      // do what you need
  }
  ```

If you need more information refer to [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) JavaDoc

If it is not HTTP Request you can figure out what class this `sampler` variable refers to as

```
log.info(sampler.getClass().getName());
```

figure out class name from jmeter.log file and look for [JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/).

For more information regarding Beanshell scripting refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Yep, seems good. I can use arguments, thanks. So, there is no way to access to query in "body data" tab?

Comment: If you're looking for raw body which cannot be represented as name-value pairs it would be the value of the very first argument. You can refer it as `sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())`

Comment: Getting Error :   `Typed variable declaration : Class: Arguments not found in namespace `

Comment: @DmitriT above said functions to retrieve IP and Path were reversed each other, please modify it.

Comment: Just stumbled across this. For me, these bits were missing. Needed imports: `import org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument;import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;` and to get the correct sampler, use the context `ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments()`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks **@Dmitri T**

I was getting

``` 13:28:13 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;    sampler.getHeaderManag . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: Arguments not found in namespace ```

 error while using

```
Arguments arguments = sampler.getArguments();
for (int i=0;i<arguments.getArgumentCount();i++)
{
    Argument argument = arguments.getArgument(i);
    String name = argument.getName();
    String value = argument.getValue();
    // do what you need
}
```

After importing

`import org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;`

**I solved this**